# Android AVD manager not launching

Tags: android, android-emulator

I recently installed `ADT` and `AVD Manager` through eclipse plugin update.
I restarted eclipse-Juno after the installation. 
But when I try starting the "AVD Manager" for creating a Virtual device the following
exception is thrown in the Workspace tab. Could anyone suggest the workaround

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdInfo.getDeviceName(AvdInfo.java:158)
>     at
>   com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.DeviceManagerPage.fillDevices(DeviceManagerPage.java:497)
>     at
>   com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.DeviceManagerPage.fillTable(DeviceManagerPage.java:357)
>     at
>   com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.DeviceManagerPage.createContents(DeviceManagerPage.java:259)
>     at
>   com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.DeviceManagerPage.(DeviceManagerPage.java:130)
>     at
>   com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.AvdManagerWindowImpl1.createDeviceTab(AvdManagerWindowImpl1.java:210)
>     at
>   com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.AvdManagerWindowImpl1.createContents(AvdManagerWindowImpl1.java:193)
>     at
>   com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.AvdManagerWindowImpl1.open(AvdManagerWindowImpl1.java:133)
>     at
>   com.android.sdkuilib.repository.AvdManagerWindow.open(AvdManagerWindow.java:94)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.actions.AvdManagerAction.run(AvdManagerAction.java:62)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.runWithEvent(WWinPluginAction.java:229)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)

Comment: Check this one out 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389680

Comment: Hello Swati , Thanks for pointing out to the solution page.It works. I referred to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40400