# NullPointerExcepton in Android Studio plugin Android Support

Tags: android-studio

I am getting the following exception in Android Studio plugin Android Support.

To get out of this error, I updated the Android Studio to 14.1, but studio just builds the app but not runs it.

```
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
at  com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.parseAvdInfo(AvdManager.java:1616)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.buildAvdList(AvdManager.java:1577)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.<init>(AvdManager.java:350)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.getInstance(AvdManager.java:373)
at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.getAvdManager(AndroidFacet.java:585)
at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.getAvdManagerSilently(AndroidFacet.java:571)
at org.jetbrains.android.run.DeviceChooser.<init>(DeviceChooser.java:143)
at org.jetbrains.android.run.ExtendedDeviceChooserDialog.<init>(ExtendedDeviceChooserDialog.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.execute(AndroidRunningState.java:263)
at com.intellij.execution.runners.DefaultProgramRunner.doExecute(DefaultProgramRunner.java:38)
at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidDebugRunner.doExec(AndroidDebugRunner.java:144)
at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidDebugRunner.doExecute(AndroidDebugRunner.java:135)
at com.intellij.execution.runners.GenericProgramRunner$1.execute(GenericProgramRunner.java:48)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl$2.run(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:208)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.runWhenSmart(DumbServiceImpl.java:95)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl$1$1.run(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:172)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:524)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: This is best addressed to the plugin support bugtracker, forum or email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Why this happens

```
at  com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.parseAvdInfo(AvdManager.java:1616)
```

The error seems to be in Android SDK library [Android Virtual Device Manager](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/avd-manager.html). It tries to open a file, and some argument in File constructor is null.

#### Solution:

> I installed the needed plugins again..and it works

#### What else can be done in similar situations:

1. Plugin damaged -> reinstall the plugin.
2. SDK damaged -> reinstall Android SDK.
3. Wrong version used -> check the used version or update Android SDK.

Comment: i reinstalled SDK but error remains the same. even i tried to execute android command it throws the same error..

Comment: i installed the needed plugins again..and it works..thanks man.

Comment: I reinstalled Android Studio. Reinstalles the Android Support plugin. Nothing works. Updated Android SDK. Nothing works

Comment: @MSI then ask another question. Add full error stacktrace and versions of Java SDK, Android studio and plugins.

Answer (score 14):

I Slove it  by this  step
you should delete this file  that you can do it .

go to  the  path :"C:\Users\Administrator.android\avd"
and  delete all the  avd folders files .

try again ,you can get it.

Comment: I deleted all AVD via Android Virtual Device manager and the problem has gone. Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be due to virtual devices that are already created are causing problems.

How I solved this issue:

1. Delete all folders from `C:\Users\<userName>\.android\avd`
2. Recreate virtual device from avd manager

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by editing build.gradle file and synch your project again.
I edited following line 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3' and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by opening the AVD Manager in Android Studio and uninstalling and reinstalling my emulators.