# NullPointerException at AVD Manager

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-virtual-device

Since I update for Android Studio Version 1.4, the AVD manager does not launch.
Aithough I try uninstall and install Android Studio and SDK manager and JDK newer version, not solved.

When project try to run, error massages come like following. and not running.
I think AVD Manager have something wrong.Why could not launch AVD manager and run project?

```
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.parseAvdInfo(AvdManager.java:1624)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.buildAvdList(AvdManager.java:1585)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.<init>(AvdManager.java:351)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.getInstance(AvdManager.java:374)
at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.getAvdManager(AndroidFacet.java:400)
at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.getAvdManagerSilently(AndroidFacet.java:386)
at org.jetbrains.android.run.DeviceChooser.<init>(DeviceChooser.java:150)
at org.jetbrains.android.run.ExtendedDeviceChooserDialog.<init>(ExtendedDeviceChooserDialog.java:130)
at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.execute(AndroidRunningState.java:244)
at com.intellij.execution.runners.DefaultProgramRunner.doExecute(DefaultProgramRunner.java:33)
at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidDebugRunner.doExec(AndroidDebugRunner.java:125)
at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidDebugRunner.doExecute(AndroidDebugRunner.java:119)
at com.intellij.execution.runners.GenericProgramRunner$1.execute(GenericProgramRunner.java:43)
at com.intellij.execution.RunProfileStarter.execute(RunProfileStarter.java:39)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl$3.run(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:219)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.updateFinished(DumbServiceImpl.java:269)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.access$800(DumbServiceImpl.java:52)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl$9.run(DumbServiceImpl.java:439)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:569)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: and I would love to know how to solve this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate please check it http://stackoverflow.com/a/30346424/4146722

Comment: Thanks, man.but I already tried it..