# Null pointer exception creating a new project Android Studio (virtualToIoFile)

Tags: android, android-studio, exception, nullpointerexception, new-project

I am using android studio 2.2, its showing null pointer exception when to create new project by clicking  "file>> new >> new project>>"

EDIT: Everything works fine untill i click on "Finish" button in the end of creating new project.

and i also updated android studio and sdk to latest version  that also didn't work.. also tried to disable plugins but it wont work, need help!!!

[image]

```
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VfsUtilCore.virtualToIoFile(VfsUtilCore.java:371)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.recipe.RenderingContext$Builder.<init>(RenderingContext.java:300)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.recipe.RenderingContext$Builder.newContext(RenderingContext.java:313)
**at com.android.tools.idea.npw.deprecated.ConfigureAndroidProjectPath.performFinishingOperation(ConfigureAndroidProjectPath.java:170)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.deprecated.ConfigureAndroidProjectPath.canPerformFinishingActions(ConfigureAndroidProjectPath.java:141)**
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard.doFinish(DynamicWizard.java:649)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.NewProjectWizardDynamic.doFinish(NewProjectWizardDynamic.java:275)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard$1.run(DynamicWizard.java:422)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$5.run(CoreProgressManager.java:227)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$8.run(CoreProgressManager.java:357)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
 at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressMa    nager.java:127)
at     com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$13$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:633)
    at   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java  :369)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After researching, i change the old projects path to somewhere else and it worked. was a little problem but annoyed me a lot.

Comment: why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

A simple and easy solution to this is to close the android studio and go in windows, **C:\Users{YOUR_ACCOUNT}.AndroidStudio )** and delete the .AndroidStudio folder.

This folder basically contains the settings for the android studio so when we update the android studio, it's settings does not update automatically.

Now after deleting this folder open your Android studio and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some issues with the Android SDK library.
Try to re install it and verify that you have installed all the required Support Library.

You should not have any issues if you follow the Android Developer guide.
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Possible duplicate with :

[NullPointerExcepton in Android Studio plugin Android Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345134/nullpointerexcepton-in-android-studio-plugin-android-support)

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: what should i do now??

Comment: Are you still receiving the same Null Pointer Exception errors?

What's your Java version?

Comment: jdk and jre version(1.8.0_65)

Comment: Try to invalidate cache and restart. File -> Invalidate Cache.