# Android: IllegalStateException in Android Support when executing Unit Tests

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, illegalstateexception

I'm trying to run some Unit Tests in Andoid Studio. In the "Run Configurations"-tab I've made it so that my JUnit searches the entire project for tests. My JRE is configured for 1.8 and I've got Code Coverage enabled. However, every time I try and run my tests, I get the following "IDE Fatal Errors":

```
Unable to determine list of modules to build
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to determine list of modules to build
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTaskProvider.createBuilder(MakeBeforeRunTaskProvider.java:357)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTaskProvider.executeTask(MakeBeforeRunTaskProvider.java:255)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTaskProvider.executeTask(MakeBeforeRunTaskProvider.java:86)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl$3.run(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:317)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:369)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've tried to google a solution and this thread came close: [NullPointerExcepton in Android Studio plugin Android Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345134/nullpointerexcepton-in-android-studio-plugin-android-support), but my SDK's and plugins are up-to-date and that didn't really solve it.

Thanks already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your "Run Configurations", "Test kind" should be changed from "All in package" to "All in directory". 
By doing this, you can configure the "Use classpath for module"-field to app. The "Directory"-field should also point to your test directory.

That should solve the issue.

Comment: this fix issue, but running `./gradlew test` still triggers it =/ weird behavior