# cannot create a virtual device in Android (An error occurred while creating the AVD.)

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a virtual device in Android studio but it give me a error message:

> "An error occurred while creating the AVD. See idea.log for details."

device I was trying to create was PIXEL API 25 with nougat as OS. Below was shown in my idea.log file.

> WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Exception during AvdManager initialization: java.lang.NullPointerException

Full log:

```
2017-11-14 07:28:30,532 [2498358]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Exception during AvdManager initialization: java.lang.NullPointerException 
2017-11-14 07:28:32,804 [2500630]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Exception during AvdManager initialization: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Have you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345134/nullpointerexcepton-in-android-studio-plugin-android-support

Comment: i deleted everything on avd folder and it worked.