# Unable to create AVD in Android Studio Mac

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

When trying to create a new virtual device on `Android Studio`, I receive an error,

An error occurred while creating the `AVD`. See `idea.log` for more info.

The error I found is

> 2018-01-31 10:01:34,090 [se-915-b08]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/Name/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.ini

Comment: Just doing a quick search, might be worth [deleting your AVD folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47276541/cannot-create-a-virtual-device-in-androidan-error-occurred-while-creating-the-a) (provided you don't have any other AVD devices you want to keep), or [check if the AVD plugin is damaged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30346424/469080)

Comment: Where do I go on Mac to remove the AVD folder?

Comment: `/Users/Name/.android/avd` like it says in the log file

Comment: Sorry, everything *within* the AVD folder, not the folder itself

Comment: Strangely, the .android folder is not there. Is there a way of showing hidden folders on mac?

Comment: In Finder you can go directly to a folder using a path with Cmd + G (as far as I remember)

Comment: I have found the folder but there doesnt seem to have any files or folders inside it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

It can be fixed by changing owner of `~/.android` to  by executing `sudo chown <your_user_name> .android` on terminal.

Answer (score 2):

I started having this issue after I upgraded to MacOS Monterrey. I tried the changing permission solution but no success. The fix for me was to disable and enable back the Android Emulator by doing the following:

1. On **Android Studio**, go to **Tools** -> **SDK Manager** -> **SDK Tools**
2. Uncheck **Android Emulator** and click on **Apply**
3. Check back **Android Emulator** and click on **Apply**

After that I was able to create new AVDs without issue.

Answer (score 1):

This error occures because android studio cant see your .android file
Find file ~/.android

```
cd ~/.android
```

you should be out of .android file (at least it worked like this on me otherwise it gives error **chown: .android: No such file or directory**)

```
cd ..
```

then give permission to file

```
sudo chown <your_user_name> .android
```

enter your password if asks
then **try again creating avd** in android studio

Answer (score 0):

For me, I could not even find `idea.log` file. I tried many things but updating android studio (4.2.1 at the moment) and other components to the latest finally fixed it. Although, for the record I did change the owner of `.android` folder to my username. But that on itself didn't fix it even if it might have been part of the fix.