# An internal error occurred during: "Launching MyFirstApp". java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've been having problems with Eclipse (Juno) when launching an application for android. I keep getting issues with the SDK not parsing and the application not launching. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!
Here is my code:

```
    package com.example.myfirstapp;

    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
}
```

And here is my Console

```
[2014-09-09 11:43:47 - MyFirstApp] ------------------------------

[2014-09-09 11:43:47 - MyFirstApp] Android Launch!

[2014-09-09 11:43:47 - MyFirstApp] adb is running normally.

[2014-09-09 11:43:47 - MyFirstApp] Performing com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity activity launch

[2014-09-09 11:43:47 - MyFirstApp] Error during launch: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: can you post some more log cat after `Error during launch: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue and solved it several times, with several different methods.

First of all, try close Eclipse and restart it.

If no good, try close Eclipse again and run `/path/to/your/eclipse -clean`, or you can do this in first step, instead of simply restarting it.

However, if it still cannot work well, maybe there's something wrong with AVD setting, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143392/eclipse-launch-error-when-trying-to-run-an-android-app).